# CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials with screen block (shading)

Tags: c++, c, security, winapi

Is there any way to use CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials with "shading" remaining desktop? (blocking)

It's achievable (shading), when using ShellExecuteEx with "runas" argument in lpVerb, so ShellExecuteEx executing task with admin rights and "shading" background. But it only executes something, without saving login/password.

Example of ShellExecuteEx with shading is here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Elevating-During-Runtime

```
int elevate()
{
    wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath)))
    {
        // Launch itself as admin
        SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { sizeof(sei) };
        sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
        sei.lpFile = szPath;
        sei.hwnd = NULL;
        sei.nShow = SW_NORMAL;

        if (!ShellExecuteExW(&sei))
        {
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
            if (dwError == ERROR_CANCELLED)
            {
                // The user refused to allow privileges elevation.
                //std::cout << "End user did not allow elevation" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _exit(1);  // Quit itself
        }
    }
}
```

Example of CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/asking-the-user-for-credentials

```
void getCredentials()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD   dwResult;
    PVOID   pvInAuthBlob = NULL;
    ULONG   cbInAuthBlob = 0;
    PVOID   pvAuthBlob = NULL;
    ULONG   cbAuthBlob = 0;
    CREDUI_INFOW ui;
    ULONG   ulAuthPackage = 0;
    BOOL    fSave = FALSE;
    TCHAR pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1];
    TCHAR pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1];
    TCHAR domain[CREDUI_MAX_DOMAIN_TARGET_LENGTH+1];
    DWORD maxLenName =  CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH+1;
    DWORD maxLenPassword =  CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH+1;
    DWORD maxLenDomain = CREDUI_MAX_DOMAIN_TARGET_LENGTH+1;


    // Display a dialog box to request credentials.
    ui.cbSize = sizeof(ui);
    ui.hwndParent = GetConsoleWindow();
    ui.pszMessageText = L"The Proxy Server requires user name and password";
    ui.pszCaptionText = L"Proxy Authentication";
    ui.hbmBanner = NULL;

    dwResult = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(
               &ui,             // Customizing information
               0,               // Error code to display
               &ulAuthPackage,  // Authorization package
               pvInAuthBlob,    // Credential byte array
               cbInAuthBlob,    // Size of credential input buffer
               &pvAuthBlob,     // Output credential byte array
               &cbAuthBlob,     // Size of credential byte array
               &fSave,          // Select the save check box.
               CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT
           );
    if (dwResult == NO_ERROR)
    {
        CredUnPackAuthenticationBufferA(0,
                                    pvAuthBlob,
                                    cbAuthBlob,
                                    pszName,
                                    &maxLenName,
                                    domain,
                                    &maxLenDomain,
                                    pszPwd,
                                    &maxLenPassword);
        SecureZeroMemory(pvAuthBlob, cbAuthBlob);
        CoTaskMemFree(pvAuthBlob);
        pvAuthBlob = NULL;

        SecureZeroMemory(pszName, sizeof(pszName));
        SecureZeroMemory(pszPwd, sizeof(pszPwd));
    }
    else
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwResult);
        if (pvInAuthBlob)
        {
            SecureZeroMemory(pvInAuthBlob, cbInAuthBlob);
            CoTaskMemFree(pvInAuthBlob);
            pvInAuthBlob = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From the sounds of it, you want to have the `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` run on the secure desktop. In that case, write a program that just calls `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`, `ShellExecuteEx` it, and have it return its input. I doubt that will somehow strengthen the system you are trying to implement. If anything, it'll just have credentials leak into the unprotected world. With that said, what's the *problem* you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @IInspectable , the problem is: gain login/password for user, that has an access to shared folder (network drive in local net), and then save path to that folder to a program's config. I didn't understand your algorithm: you suggest to `ShellExecuteEx` something, that calls `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` ? But in that case user will enter credentials twice: first for `ShellExecuteEx`, and second for `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` ...

Comment: All of that is understood: You're prepared to get it wrong, at least once. Why do you need an alternative that lets you get it wrong more than once?

Comment: @IInspectable , idk, well all that I wanted was screen-shadowing. Of course there's alternative just to call `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` without shadowing. It just looks less official and serious :) and it's easier to miss in a bunch of other windows.

Comment: Apparently, you do not understand what's actually happening in what you call *"shadowing"*/*"shading"*. This isn't a visual gimmick. It's a dedicated, [secure desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-switch-to-the-secure-desktop-when-prompting-for-elevation). Do you want to implement a secure system or a visual gimmick?

Comment: [CredUIPromptForCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/asking-the-user-for-credentials) is enough which is just like [UserConsentVerifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier?view=winrt-22621).

Comment: @IInspectable , `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` is enough. But if you provide any link or other info about secure desktop, this could be very helpful. Also thanks a lot for info you've shared already.